# Document Approval Workflow in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library, content-approval

Firstly, apologies if this has been answered somewhere, but I have spent 2 days hunting through Google, including results here, and I haven't found an answer yet, so I thought someone here may be able to help.

- I am using an on-prem SharePoint 2013 farm. I only want to use the 2013 Workflow Manager (no 2010 workflows, please).
- My library has major and minor versions, requires check in/out, and also document approval before it's made available to everyone.
- I have been trying to create a workflow (currently in SharePoint Designer) which can ultimately approve a document.

Does anyone have any ideas how to get this to work?

I can't update the Approval Status field. I can't find an action that will allow the document to be approved (unless I want to use a 2010 workflow, which I don't). I considered using a custom field to set the status to approved, and wondered if I could use a timer job to properly approve these records overnight or something, but even that hit a snag when I did the necessary check out / check in around the update of the field, and the document ended up checked in as a minor version instead of a major, which meant it couldn't be approved anyway. I also can't find a way to tell it to check in as a major version.

Anyone have any suggestions?

- Is document approval even possible with a SharePoint 2013 workflow (and force check in/out)?
- Is the timer job a good idea? Could I write a custom workflow action in Visual Studio to accomplish the "check in as major version" idea?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.
When you click the approval process link in the Text based Designer in Sharepoint Designer 
go to task behaviour ( In short edit the workflow)
go to "When the task completes"
add a line inside if statement " set content approval ... approve (author).."
same for rejected. In that case select "Rejected"

save and publish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't see any "approval process" link in SharePoint Designer using a SharePoint 2013 Workflow. Are you sure you're not referring to the 2010 Workflow?

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, there is always the possibility to call some of the SharePoint REST web services. The following answer has what you need: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/199060/75504